# php date and date time

Tags: php, date

Strange behaviour of php DateTime class

```
$x = '23120-7-7';
$x = new \DateTime($x);
var_dump($x);
```

Gives

```
object(DateTime)#988 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2000-07-07 23:12:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

I wanted to validate date but there is only datetime class in php. How can i check for

that my date is valid ?

Comment: Using regex? I find this online test tool very easy to use: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ Then look on the right side of the screen, see the comunity tab, and find yourself a suitable regular expression to match your date format. Or type one yourself ofcourse. Would this regex help you: ^(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)$ its for datetime format like YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date_create_from_format

```
$x = '23120-7-7';
$x = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $x);
var_dump($x);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```

To see the error detail:

```
$errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
var_dump($errors);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [7]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(2) {
    [4]=>
    string(40) "The separation symbol could not be found"
    [7]=>
    string(13) "Trailing data"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "checkdate" method for that if you want a direct answer. Firstly explode date with dash(-) maybe, I don't know what style date you are using, then use checkdate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to timestamp then set a new date with the format you need date("y-m-d",timestamp), and you check for errors